# Angular - useExisting ngForm optional

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-dependency-injection

I need to inject the form from a parent component into a child component to be able to validate the child component input like so:

```html
    <form #formReference="ngForm">
     <child-component></child-component>
     <child-component></child-component>
     <child-component></child-component>

     <p>{{formReference.form.valid}}</p>
    </form>
```

Right now i have added this provider on the child component to make it use the parent form and it works fine

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
```

However i still need to be able to use the child component as before without a form. Is there a way to make this provider optional? At the moment if a use my child component without a form wrapping it i get the error

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CustomModule)[NgForm -> NgForm -> NgForm -> NgForm -> NgForm]
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use useFactory method to provide optional dependency, by setting Optional flag in deps array

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-component',
  templateUrl: './child-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-component.component.scss'],
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      deps: [[Optional, NgForm]],
      useFactory: (ngForm: NgForm) => ngForm,
    },
  ],
})
```

Comment: Great solution, it resolves NullInjectorError. But in that parent component with form I have got another error:
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
    control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Have you added name attribute on the input element?

Answer (score 0):

In child component remove providers and inject `NgControl` directly via constructor using [@Optional](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) and [@Self](https://angular.io/api/core/Self)

```
constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
   if (this.ngControl != null) this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
}
```